# A plot of Gibbs energy and entropy at constant pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy, chemical-potential

[image]

The figure shows the plot of the variation of Gibbs energy with temperature and of entropy with temperature at constant pressure. ( This plot is for a second order phase transition)

We know that $\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_{p}=-S$ , more the entropy steeper the slope of $G$. But the plot doesn't follow that

Why is that so?.

Comment: It looks to me like the plot does follow that.

Comment: Thank you Mr Chet Miller for your time.If we look at Gibbs energy at low temperatures the slope should be small because the entropy is small there, but the slope is steep there.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about the axes' labels? Can you give a reference to the source of the figure?

Comment: http://faculty.chem.queensu.ca/people/faculty/mombourquette/Chem221/5_PhaseChanges/PhaseThermo.asp